# Python: Histogram return wrong values for counts (EDIT: more general with example)

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

EDIT: Ive found a general example where it doesnt work either!
I am trying to extract the data for a histogram, but different counts seem wrong. As an example code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
data = np.random.rand(1000000)
bins = np.arange(0,1,0.0001)
a,b,c = plt.hist(data,bins)
```

This gives me [this rather messy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1w50.png) histogram, and i've saved the counts as a and the interval as b. Now, plotting a and b, I should expect the same histogram, right? But that's not what I get:

```
plt.scatter(b[0:len(b)-1],a,s=2)
```

which gives me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y45Pe.png), which doesnt match at all! Furthurmore, when I try and find the maximum value of a, it gives me 144, which fits fine with the scatterplot, but not with the histogram function.

If I count the numbers myself with the following code:

```
len(np.intersect1d(np.where(data>=b[np.argmax(a)]),np.where(data<b[np.argmax(a)+1])))
```

then it also gives me 144, in accordance with the values. So is the displayed histogram just wrong for some reason, and I should ignore it and just take the extracted data?

**Old, unedited post:**

For a physics course I am trying to bin my results in the following way:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as ss
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
plt.rc("font", family=["Helvetica", "Arial"]) 
plt.rc("axes", labelsize=18)
plt.rc("xtick", labelsize=16, top=True, direction="in")
plt.rc("ytick", labelsize=16, right=True, direction="in")
plt.rc("axes", titlesize=22)
plt.rc("legend", fontsize=16)

data_Ra = np.loadtxt('Ra226_cal2_ch001.txt',skiprows=5)
t_Ra = data_Ra[:,0]*10**-8 # time in seconds 
channels_Ra = data_Ra[:,1]
channels_Ra = channels_Ra[np.where(channels_Ra>0)] # removing all the measurements at channel = 0
intervalspace = 2 #The intervals in which we count
bins=np.arange(0,4000,intervalspace)


counts, intervals , stuff = plt.hist(channels_Ra,bins)
plt.xlabel('Channels')
plt.ylabel('Counts')
plt.show()
```

Here, the [histogram plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCDCr.png) looks totally fine, with a max near 13000 counts. But when I then use np.max(counts), I am given about 24000, and when I try and just plot the values it gives me with:

```
plt.scatter(intervals[0:len(intervals)-1]+intervalspace/2,counts,s=1)
plt.xlabel('Channels')
plt.ylabel('Counts')
plt.title('Ra225')
plt.show()
```

it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2p1Fa.png), which is totally different, and I can't figure out why. I am expecting the scatterplot to resemble the histogram, and while the peaks are located at the same x-vales, the height do not match.

This problem is in other large datasets as well.

I dont think i'm allowed to drop the txt-file here? So im not sure how much more I can show, but any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you interpret the results in that way.

If you look at the histogram plot, you will be able to see the maximum value of the y-axis is 25,000. That means that there are some values close to 25,000. This fact can be verified in the scatter plot.

Your scatter plot shows actual values. It would be clearer if you describe how your expected plot looks like.

If you want discard some outlier points, you should apply some filtering before plotting the data.

Comment: From how I understand the variables plt.hist gives me, using the first two variables in a scatterplot should give me points matching the histogram, just unfilled below. So I expected my scatterplot to resemble the histogram, and while the peaks are at the same x-values, the height of them do not match at all. So I don't quite understand...